# Bindings for testflight Xamarin.IOS Unified

Tags: xamarin, testflight

I am looking for testflight bindings for the newest update of xamarin. Has anyone done these yet?
I am trying to make them by myself however this is not area I normally step in to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it to work, it was simpler than I thought.

I used the bindings from [Mono touch bindings](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/TestFlight)

I followed xamarins suggestions here [Update bindings](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/update_binding_unified/) updated the makefile and updated the code to use the correct references.

Then I just ran the makefile and got my dll :)